# How to manage the routes in Blade when there are same routes inside two different route groups?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, router

I have created the two resource controller inside two different route groups.
One for User
One for Admin

```
   Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'dashboard',
        "middleware" => 'auth',
        "namespace" => 'User'
        ], function (){
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
    })

   Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        "middleware" => 'auth',
        "namespace" => 'Admin'
        ], function (){
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
    })
```

I am using the 'route' keyword for assigning the routes. I am doing so because I wanted to use same views files for both.

Here is the blade file

```
<form action='{{route('projects.update', $project)}}' method="POST">
                @method('PUT')
                @csrf
    ....
    </form>
```

When I am in **/admin/projects** it is using the **admin.projects resource routes** as expected but when I am **/dashboard/projects** it should use dashboard resource route, but it is using **admin.projects.update route**.

*And also When I comment/remove the admin projects routes from the web.php, it's working fine.*

Let me know why it is happening. And what is the best solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command `php artisan route:list` and you will found the same alias name in both so you have to make alias unique.

To do so,

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'dashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard.',
    "middleware" => 'auth',
    "namespace" => 'User'
    ], function (){
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
});



Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'as' => 'admin.',
        "middleware" => 'auth',
        "namespace" => 'Admin'
        ], function (){
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');
    });
```

So you need to use this as `admin.projects.index` and `dashboard.projects.index`